# ACM Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, templates, acm

I'm using [this template](http://www.sigecom.org/ec16/EC16-latex.zip) for ACM paper. When I compile the template (windows, texmaker) the citations are undefined.
The .tex file contains

```
% Bibliography
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format-Journals}
\bibliography{acmsmall-sample-bibfile}
```

and the .bst, .bib files are also contained in the same folder.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you run BibTeX after running LaTeX? I experience no problems running pdfLaTeX, BibTeX, and pdfLaTeX twice more to create the full document, including the bibliography and the citation call-outs.

Comment: I have re-tagged your question since it is not about `biblatex`, you are using standard BibTeX styles. Have a look at [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864). Do you get any errors or warnings? What does the `.blg` file say (is there even one)?

Comment: Is there any news here?